# I'm trying to some parameters using params[:id] in a controller. However it is not accepting any input after special characters such as ? or #

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, special-characters

I'm trying to some parameters using params[:id] in a controller. However it is not accepting any input after special characters such as ? or #.

For instance:

```
localhost:3000/analysis/good?bad
```

is the url.
Here is the code for Analysis_controller.rb

```
class AnalysisController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @analyzer = params[:id]
    ....
    ....
  end
end
```

Here `@analyzer` contains only `good`, not `good?bad`

How to resolve this issue? Are there any alternatives to params[:id] which might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to encode you parameters, else it goes in the hash :

localhost:3000/analysis/good%3Fbad

In Ruby, you can use `CGI::escape`.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to name that param something else, let's say `type`:

```
localhost:3000/analysis/good?type=bad
```

Then in your controller you can do `@analyzer = params[:type]`

You can pass those params to your URL helper like so:

```
analysis_path(id: "good", type: "bad")
```